# gridView doesn't show anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

i'm trying to show the result of a select query into a gridview but i can't to get it work :(.
this is my table :

```
cartID    userID    productID
-------------------------------
001          A111111    file1
002          A111111    fileq
003          A222222    file2
004          A222222    file3
005          A111111    file4
006          A333333    file5
007          A333333    file6
```

this is the result of the query :

```
nomProduit    prix    
---------------------
batata          200    
bicyclette      23   
kawkaw          2
```

this is my query

```
SELECT Produits.nomProduit,Produits.prix
FROM [Products].[dbo].[shoppingCart],[Products].[dbo].[Produits]
WHERE produitID=Id and userID = @userID
```

this is my aspx code:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="shoppingCartDS" AllowSorting="True">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="shoppingCartDS" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnString %>"     SelectCommand="selectPanier" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
           <asp:Parameter Name="userID" Type="String"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and this is my cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strCurrentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        shoppingCartDS.SelectParameters.Add("userid", DbType.Guid, strCurrentUserId.ToString());

    }
```

so help me guys please :(

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to return UserID aswell

```
SELECT Produits.nomProduit,Produits.prix, userID
FROM [Products].[dbo].[shoppingCart],[Products].[dbo].[Produits]
WHERE produitID=Id and userID = @userID
```

And Modify your GridView to add bound COlumn and DataKeyNames property

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="userID" DataSourceID="shoppingCartDS">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID"  />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="nomProdit" HeaderText="nomProdit" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Prix" HeaderText="Prix" />                
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```